# Adding WMS layer to geoserver for cesium

Tags: geoserver, cesiumjs, wms

I was asked to set up offline map for Cesium. Thus, I set up Geoserver with Tomcat Apache.. I have heard from various forum on Accessing a WMS layer from Geoserver and adding it in Cesium globe.. But my question is how to add WMS layer? Is it by downloading image map or do I need to draw a map?

The forum which i found for accesing a WMS layer are found below
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190459/accessing-a-wms-layer-from-geoserver-and-adding-it-in-cesium-globe

Comment: this would be better asked on http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: do you want to know how to add a WMS to GeoServer or Cesium?

Comment: I want to know on how to add a WMS to geoserver ..

Comment: Can you please help me in adding a WMS to geoserver @iant

Answer (score 1):

This is known as a [cascaded WMS](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/cascaded/wms.html), GeoServer treats it as just another raster data store (roughly).

Simply, go to the WMS Datastore (right at the bottom of the stores list) and fill in the GetCapabilities URL and the name of the store. Once the store is created you can publish the layers as with any other store.

Comment: Will it publish layer to the  Cesium from the geoserver

Comment: cesium needs to request the wms layer from geoserver

Comment: About the wms layer, do I have to configure the layer after creating a store??? The link which you gave it to me state that I need to configure the external WMS layer. I do not understand on what is the purpose of configuring the external WMS layer...